# How does my bank reverse connect back to my mobile phone?

Tags: android, http, networking, connection

I was wandering how this works programming wise.

If I log into my online banking website on my pc, As I login, the app on my android device popups up and lets me enter the OTP.

How do they achieve this without polling the server? As obviously the phones Ip will change all the time, depending which cellphone tower you are on, if you are on wifi etc.

I would really like to know how they went about implementing this, as I see it to be very useful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser

Comment: I don't find your link relevant. That involves launching an app from the device its self. Not from a webserver / internet

Comment: The linked page describes how to launch an app from a web page using a special URL scheme `<a href="my.special.scheme://other/parameters/here">`, which would most likely be how the bank launches the OTP app.

Comment: It is possible to run a server on an android device, which could listen for incoming connections from remote hosts.  But, I would be surprised if this is how the functionality that you describe is implemented.  Are you sure that there is not a program or an app on the android device that has a socket open to the server (or is polling the server)?